# Changing input type from text to multi select dropdown - skill taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, themes, tags, forms, code

Really need help with a wordpress code please.

I have a field on a form which adds tags to the post. Problem is, its free for anyone to enter anything. This keep populating the "skill" taxonomy. The code for that is:

```
<div class="form-group skill-control">
<label><?php _e('Tags', 'themes');?></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-field skill" id="skill" placeholder="<?php _e("Enter tags", 'themes');?>" name=""  autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" >
<ul class="skills-list" id="skills_list"></ul>
</div>
```

What I want is, it will instead have a dropdown multi select. The dropdown will get populated using the list in skills taxonomy. The code I have so far is:

```
<div class="input-group">
<label for="skill"><?php _e('Specialist Skills', 'themes');?></label>
<?php
ae_tax_dropdown('skill',
array('attr' => 'data-chosen-width="100%" data-chosen-disable-search="" multiple data-placeholder="' . __("Choose tags", 'themes') . '"',
'class' => 'chosen chosen-multi multi-tax-item required',
'hide_empty' => false,
'hierarchical' => true,
'id' => 'skill',
'show_option_all' => false,
)
);?>
</div>
```

At the moment, the code is working on the from, but not inserting the tags in the post! When I retrieve the post, there are no tags.

If I use the previous code, it adds the tags to the post.

Please help! What am I doing wrong?

Complete code:

```
if (isset($_GET['return_url'])) {
    $return = $_GET['return_url'];
} else {
    $return = home_url();
}
$currency_code = ae_currency_code(false);
?>
<div class="step-wrapper step-post" id="step-post">
    <form class="post-job  post et-form" id="">
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="post_title" class="input-label"><?php _e('Let\'s name your request', 'themes');?></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-item input-full" name="post_title" value="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row clearfix <?php echo ('1' == ae_get_option('custom_price_mode') || is_super_admin($user_ID)) ? 'has-price-field' : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ('1' == ae_get_option('custom_price_mode') || is_super_admin($user_ID)): ?>
                <?php


?>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <label for="et_budget"><?php printf(__('Your budget (%s)', 'themes'), $currency_code);?></label>
                        <input type="number" name="et_budget"  class="input-item et_budget" >

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif?>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 delivery-area">
                <div class="input-group delivery-time">
                    <label for="time_delivery"><?php _e('Max time for a specialist to deliver (Day)', 'themes');?></label>
                    <input type="number" name="time_delivery" value="" class="input-item time-delivery" min="0">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 category-area">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="job_category"><?php _e('Category', 'themes');?></label>
                    <?php
                        ae_tax_dropdown('job_category',
                        array('attr' => 'data-chosen-width="100%" data-chosen-disable-search=""  data-placeholder="' . __("Choose categories", 'themes') . '"',
                            'class' => 'chosen chosen-single tax-item required',
                            'hide_empty' => false,
                            'hierarchical' => true,
                            'id' => 'job_category',
                            'show_option_all' => false,
                        )
                    );?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="mb-20"><?php _e('Description', 'themes')?></label>
                <?php wp_editor('', 'post_content', ae_editor_settings());?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="skill"><?php _e('Preferred Specialist Skills', 'themes');?></label>
            <?php
                ae_tax_dropdown('skill',
                array('attr' => 'data-chosen-width="100%" data-chosen-disable-search="" multiple data-placeholder="' . __("Choose tags", 'themes') . '"',
                    'class' => 'chosen-multi multi-tax-item required',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'id' => 'skill',
                    'show_option_all' => false,
                )
            );?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group skill-control">
            <label><?php _e('Tags', 'themes');?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-field skill" id="skill" placeholder="<?php _e("Enter microjob tags", 'themes');?>" name=""  autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" >
            <ul class="skills-list" id="skills_list"></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="<?php mje_button_classes(array('btn-save', 'waves-effect', 'waves-light'))?>" type="submit"><?php _e('SAVE', 'themes');?></button>
            <a href="<?php echo $return; ?>" class="btn-discard"><?php _e('DISCARD', 'themes');?></a>
            <input type="hidden" class="input-item post-service_nonce" name="_wpnonce" value="<?php echo de_create_nonce('ae-job_post-sync'); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" class="input-item is_submit_request" name="is_submit_request" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="input-item post_type" name="post_type" value="<?php echo JOB_RECRUIT;?>">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of the codes you show will insert tags in the post. So there is something missing, possibly a script that is triggered by the `id` of the form. Moreover, `ae_tax_dropdown` is not a standard WP-function.

Comment: Please see the post above, I have posted the total code. My apologies for not doing it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<form>`-tag doesn't have an 'action' defined. This is an example of how it should look:

```
<form action="/form-retrieval-page.php" method="post">
```

So when you submit the form, then nothing is passed.